# how do i solve this problem on installing Cordova by cmd

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I am a new user. i am trying to export mu game in construdt2 to apk by Cordova cli.
when I want install Cordova in cmd, I see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x82zX.png)

please help me soon.
I tried more than 10 times to install it but I couldn't. at last time I saw theses errors.
best regards
ehsan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have a version installed and npm can't overwrite the cordova dir. Try to uninstall before, then reboot (just in case), then install again

```
 npm uninstall cordova -g
 reboot
 npm install cordova -g
```

Also make sure you run your prompt as admin